# Static classes and the Business Objects COM Library

Tags: .net, business-objects, static-classes

The following code below is from a winforms application that on a button event opens up an instance of business objects 6.5, refreshes the report and then dumps the data in the report into a csv file, and then quits the business objects instance.

The first time i run the code it works perfectly, however if i run it again i get an exception on the line

```
boApp.LoginAs(userName, Password, false, null);
```

The exception thrown is 'Invalid Object'.

I'm assuming this is down to the fact that boApp hasn't been re-initialised, and that it's my lack of knowledge regarding static classes that's the issue.

The calling method is this:

```
BO_Control.RefreshBusinessObjects(boReportsFolder, boExportsFolder, boReportName, exportFileName, startDate, endDate);
```

and this is the BO_Control class

```
static class BO_Control
{

    static busobj.Application boApp = new busobj.Application();
    static busobj.Document testDoc;


   public static void RefreshBusinessObjects(string reportFolder, string exportFolder ,string boReportName, string exportFileName, string startDate, string endDate)      
   {


        DateTime BoStart = DateTime.Now;

        boApp.LoginAs(userName, Password, false, null);

        boApp.Interactive = false;
        boApp.Visible = false;

        GetData(reportFolder, boReportName, startDate, endDate);
        ExportData(exportFolder, exportFileName);

        Console.WriteLine("BO_Export took {0} seconds.", DateTime.Now.Subtract(BoStart));

        boApp.Quit();          
   }

   static busobj.Document GetData(string reportFolder, string reportName, string startDate, string endDate)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(reportFolder + reportName);
       testDoc = (busobj.Document)boApp.Documents.Open(reportFolder + reportName, true, false, null, null);

       //Report Start Date
       testDoc.Variables[1].Value = startDate;
       //Report End Date
       testDoc.Variables[2].Value = endDate;
       //Area. Needs to be a semi-colon delimited string
       testDoc.Variables[3].Value = "L;B;H;";

       testDoc.Refresh();

       return testDoc;

   }

   static void ExportData(string exportFolder, string exportFileName)
   {
       testDoc.Reports.get_Item(1).ExportAsText(exportFolder + exportFileName);
       //2 = DoNotSaveChanges
       testDoc.Close(2);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the instantiation of the BOApp into the RefreshBusinessObjects Method and that seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

i also use this login code, it works, but it need to click the OK button of BO login diaglog. is there some methods can skip this click button step?

Comment: Blimey, this is a blast from the past. this line should be set which will turn off all Business objects interactions boApp.Interactive = false; Are you also making sure the username and password are correct in the boApp.LoginAs(userName, Password, false, null); Method?

Comment: i think my username & pwd are right, pls see my code via the below link, and if i click the ok button of BO login diaglog, the bo app will run as usual
[click here for code](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=219784&sid=027f230af85e9b74e8fccff138288724)

Comment: I wish i could help you further but I no longer have access to Business objects 6.5 to test it.